# How to check whether if the form is validated or not in Jquery-Tools validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

The return value from `$("#myform").validator()` is an object, is there a method in [Jquery-Tools Validator](http://www.jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html) like boolean `$("#myform").isValid()`?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure but, did you try the `$("#myform").checkValidity()` to check validity programmatically as shown in your link?

Comment: yes, and it didn't work on i apply it on a form id e.g $("#myform").checkValidity();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkValidity` is not a method of the jQuery object. It's a method of the the `validator` instance stored in the element's [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) of the form (or input) element which you bound the validator to. Use:

```
$('#myform').data("validator").checkValidity()
```

To get the boolean representing the form's validity.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/4hASg/)

Comment: @Skystar3 No problem, I took a while to figure it out too. `=]` I guess storing the validator object in the `.data()` is less conflicting/error-prone than adding methods directly to the global jQuery object, hence the devs chose this way.